# Dynamics Ax Appendable lookup

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

I Have a table with a relationship set for a field which gives me the lookup.
Within the validateWrite(), i am returning true if that field is being validated, so that it doesn't throw any error.

Now I want to allow the user to add a "comma" and drop down again, selecting another (or same) value, however when selected it appends to the original value.

I have tried doing this in the Modified() method, appending the text of the this.Orig(), however this.Orig() retrieves the last saved record in the Database, and not the current value.

An example of this is the Query selection window, which is a standard Ax form and allows for this.

So is this possible?

Comment: I found a Property on the form TextEdit field for that table "ReplaceOnLookup" and set it to yes. I am assuming that the append is only Form based, and cannot be DB based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `ReplaceOnLookup` attribute to No, which will allow the user to append lookup values to the field.

Comment: Yes thats what i added to My Comment. So there is no way to do that from the Table (Keeping it in the table, instead of the UI)