# Dialog RunBase custom lookup: Alt + Down key combination doesn't work

Tags: dialog, axapta, x++

MS Dynamics AX 4.0

I have a class with a dialog that extends RunBase, a dialogField of Range type and a custom lookup for it. It works as planned but one thing upsets me.
Normal lookup opens on Alt + Down key combination, but it doesn't work in my dialog. I assume this is because "Range" EDT is not related to any TableField.
But I have my own lookup, can I force it somehow to drop down on Alt + Down?

Here is my dialog method:

```
protected Object dialog(DialogRunBase dialog, boolean forceOnClient)
{
    Object                      ret;
    ;
    ret = super(dialog, forceOnClient);
    dialogFld = new DialogField(ret, typeid(Range), 100);
    dialogFld.init(ret);
    dialogFld.lookupButton(FormLookupButton::Always);
    dialogFld.fieldControl().replaceOnLookup(false);

    return ret;
}
```

Here is my lookup, as you can see, it's based on ItemId EDT:

```
protected void Fld100_1_Lookup()
{
    TableLookup_RU          sysTableLookup = new TableLookup_RU();
    Query                   query          = new Query();
    FormRun                 lookupForm;
    QueryBuildDataSource    qbds           = query.addDataSource(tablenum(InventTable));
    ;
    sysTableLookup.parmTableId(tablenum(InventTable));
    sysTableLookup.parmCallingControl(dialogFld.fieldControl());

    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldnum(InventTable, ItemId));
    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldnum(InventTable, ItemName));

    findOrCreateRange_W(qbds, fieldnum(InventTable, ItemType), SysQuery::valueNot(ItemType::Service));

    sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);
    lookupForm = sysTableLookup.formRun();
    dialogFld.fieldControl().performFormLookup(lookupForm);
}
```

And dialogPostRun:

```
public void dialogPostRun(DialogRunbase dialog)
{
    ;
    dialog.formRun().controlMethodOverload(true);
    dialog.formRun().controlMethodOverloadObject(this);
    super(dialog);
}
```

This problem is not that critical, but it bothers me. If someone could help, I'd be really grateful.

P.S.: I could use ItemId typeId, but I need to append many items, and ItemId is only 20 chars long..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered that I don't have to use Range typeid for the dialogField. dialogField.limitText(int) works just fine, it overrides the length of EDT. So I changed dialog method like this:

```
protected Object dialog(DialogRunBase dialog, boolean forceOnClient)
   {
       Object                      ret;
       ;
       ret = super(dialog, forceOnClient);
       dialogFld = new DialogField(ret, typeid(ItemId), 100); //if typeId doesn't have relations Alt + Down doesn't work
       dialogFld.init(ret);
       dialogFld.label("@SYS72708");
       dialogFld.lookupButton(FormLookupButton::Always);
       dialogFld.limitText(200);
       dialogFld.fieldControl().replaceOnLookup(false);

       return ret;
   }
```

Comment: Of cause the variable taking the `dialogFld.value()` in `getFromDialog()` should be large enough to hold the value.

Comment: Yes, it must be at least of dialogField length. I pass `dialogFld.value()` to `Range` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new extended data type `ItemIdRange`, extend from `Range`.
Be sure to set the relation on the new type to relate to `InventTable.ItemId` to get automatic lookup.

Also the form control must have property `ReplaceOnLookup` [set to no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209605/dynamics-ax-appendable-lookup/6221008#6221008), to allow the user to add more criteria. For a `DialogRunbase` field this may be done this way:

```
FormStringControl fsc = dialogField.control();
fsc.replaceOnLookup(false);
```

The code posted in the question is then not needed.

Comment: Hi, thanks, this is certainly working solution, but I wish to make minimum customizations and would like to avoid creating new EDT. Sorry I haven't mentioned my AX version, it's 4.0. I Assume that registerOverrideMethod would do the work, as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40725646/4925022, but it's implemented only since 2012, so I can't check.